# Advice needed: placement of kick heaters

Tags: plumbing, heating

I have a question that I'm hoping someone can help me with. Attached is a diagram of a kitchen remodel I'm doing.

We've gotten the question from the plumber as to where we'd like to place two 4000btu kick heaters and I have no clue how to determine the best place.

I'm thinking that one should be on the sink cabinet and maybe one on the island? Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Why do you need these heaters? What kind of system provides your primary heating?

Comment: My wife wanted these to quickly warm up the kitchen during the winter. The primary heating source is boiler with base board heaters - apologies if this isn't what you were asking!

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking. Any chance of adding more baseboard heaters from the boiler to the kitchen?

Comment: No - not possible.

Comment: Which are the outside walls? Normal placement of heating units is near the outside walls since more heat leaves form there, so if you are trying to offset the heat loss to outside, you put the heaters close to the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't extend your primary heating system to eliminate the need for the kick heaters, I'm guessing the heaters will be electric. You'll need one circuit for each unit or maybe one circuit for both depending on the type of units you get and the installation instructions.  I would be looking to install them on each of the long sides of the island.

Answer (score 0):

I would put one on the top left corner of the cabinet. Just because there doors in other places. And one on the left of the island.

But for quick heating, fan heaters are best. Something like a bathroom heater, on a wall somewhere.